# Automapper error after updating a record with POCO classes, Unity and EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, poco

I've created an application that uses automapper, everything seems to be configured and working correctly in browse mode, however after I update a record I then get the following mapping error:

```
  AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
  Mapping types:
  Organisation -> ViewModelOrganisation
```

I've registered auttomapper in application start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        App_Start.AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
    }
```

Then done the mapping in Automapperconfig:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Organisation, ViewModelOrganisation>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Article, ViewModelArticle>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Organisation, ViewModelAdminOrg>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Branch, ViewModelBranch>().ReverseMap();
        });

    }

}
```

This hits OK when the application starts and I can browse the site. The problem occurs when I save a record (update). The information saves, however when I go back to another page to browse the site I get mapping errors.

**Update:**

Im mapping in the controller like so:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        Organisation org = new Organisation();
        ViewModelOrganisation vm = new ViewModelOrganisation();
        org = _orgService.getOrganisationByOrgID(id);
        vm = Mapper.Map(org, vm);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

The error occurs on the line:  vm = Mapper.Map(org, vm). It also occurs on other pages that use the mapper. But only after I have updated a record in my admin panel.

Comment: This is not the full error message. Please post the complete exception. Probably you are missing a mapping from a source type to a destination type, which must be added to your initialize method. Also this error is not thrown on initialization, it will be thrown when AutoMapper tries to convert from type a to type b.

Comment: If you don't know where this exception happens, start your application in Visual Studio. Open in Visual Studio Debug - Window - Exception Settings and enable the checkbox at the second option *Common Language Runtime Exception*. Then your debugger stops at the point where this exception was thrown.

Comment: @Oliver the error is thrown at vm = Mapper.Map(org, vm); in the controller, however i dont think this is the issue, as it only stops working after an update in made using entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to initializing the mapper in global.asa i was doing this in the controller itself. I had failed to remove the line(below), from the controller, where the article record was being edited:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Article, ViewModelArticle>());
```

This must have invalidated the mapping created on start up and hence my error when I went to browse the rest of the site.

**Lesson learned...Ensure to only initialise the mapper once!**

Comment: In my asp.net core project I'm using the Microsoft DI framework. So in my Startup.cs I'm calling `services.AddAutoMapper()`. Due to this fact I can inject the mapper in each constructor class as `MyClass(IMapper mapper)`. To initialize this mapper with the desired configuration I need to create (individual) classes which derive from `AutomMapper.Profile`. Within the above `AddAutoMapper()` method, it will scan the whole AppDomain for all classes which derive from `Profile` and initializes the mapper with it. This makes these things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

As your full exception message says, the mapper doesn't have a mapping from `Organisation` to `ViewModelOrganisation`. I'm not sure, but is next to the reverse mapping not also a normal mapping needed? So try adding `cfg.CreateMap<Organisation, ViewModelOrganisation>()`.

Also you can simplify your code to this:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    var org = _orgService.getOrganisationByOrgID(id);
    var vm = Mapper.Map<ViewModelOrganisation>(org);
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Using reverse map means i can use the line Mapper.Map(article, vm) or vice versa, Mapper.Map(vm, article). Useful when editing records.